# How do memory access patterns affect memory bandwidth

Tags: memory, bandwidth, latency

I am involved in a computation that allocates about 1TByte of data in main memory.
I need to understand how much memory access patterns can affect the bandwidth to the processor.

For example I read that an Intel Xeon processor can support a memory bandwidth of 65GBytes/sec. Does this mean that this bandwidth will be achieved under all memory access patterns or only under optimal access patterns?

I know that on each request for data to main memory a whole cache line (64 Bytes) is pulled in. I consider the memory access pattern optimal, if on each request the entire cache line is used before the next request is issued. The worst case would be if on each request only one double (8 Bytes) is used before the next request is issued.

Suppose I know that on each request on average out of the 8 doubles that come in I will be using only f=1,2,...,8 of these before the next request is issued. Is there an easy way to  compute the actual bandwidth I will get as a function  of f?´

Thanks in advance for all replies